# Show loading for Server Component in NextJs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, streaming, loading, next.js13

I want to show a loading skeleton instead of my Cards component whenever I search a product or filtering.
This is my code at Home page:

```
export default async function Home({ searchParams }: { searchParams: any }) {
  const allCars = await fetchCars({
    year: searchParams.year || 2022,
  });

  const isDataEmpty = !Array.isArray(allCars) || allCars.length < 1 || !allCars;

  return (
    <main>
      <SearchBar />

      {!isDataEmpty ? (
        <section>
          <div>
            {allCars?.map((car) => (
              <CarCard car={car} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </section>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h2>Oops, no results</h2>
        </div>
      )}
    </main>
  );
}
```

I can't pass props to  component and handle loading with states because my Home page is a Server component And I don't want to convert it.

I wrapped my   inside a Suspense Also I used a loading.tsx but They didn't work.

Is there any way to show loading in server component for a part of page?
(my  changes url and search params to fetch new data)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.